# How to execute send request using AJAX Post method everytime I select or click the dropdown-item

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How to execute send request using AJAX Post method every time I select or click the dropdown-item, here is my HTML code

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-large" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <a class="dropdown-item"><b>Title 1</b></a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dp1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dp2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dp3/a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dp4</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dp5</a>
                            </div>                           
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-large" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <a class="dropdown-item"><b>Title 1</b></a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" name="tryme" href="#">dp1</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" name="tryme" href="#">dp2</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" name="tryme" href="#">dp3</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" name="tryme" href="#">dp4</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" name="tryme" href="#">dp5</a>
    </div>                           
  </div>
</div>
```

Then here is some JQUERY

```
$(document).on('click',"a[name='tryme']", function(){
var value = $(this).html();
  $.ajax({
          url: 'query.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {value: value},
          success: function(data) {
                    Alert('Success');
                  }
       });
  });
});
```

Query.php

```
if(isset($_POST["value"])){
 //code goes here
}
```

try it here if you want
https://jsfiddle.net/dtku1rs9/

Comment: Hi Rayner thank you so much i tried your solution and it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Two posibilities:

1. Use event listener
2. add onClick to your drop down elements

Comment: hi Rendolp, can you show me? honestly I'm new to web development self taught thank you so much